# Is cow ever the plural of cow?

Tags: grammatical-number, dialects, animals

I was thinking about ruminants, as you do, and I noticed that, unlike with sheep or deer, *cows* is the plural of cow. I started wondering why, then it occurred to me that maybe there were dialects that used *cow* as the plural.

I tried [searching Google books](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=1920&bih=944&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQluM7SArJP9UJVGip9nI06A7vYtw%3A1579690661434&ei=pSooXqOMGsqP8gL4noOADw&q=%22a+field+of+cow%22+-shit+-poop+-parsley+-peas+-cabbage+-manure+-pies+-pats+-dung+-corn+-patties&oq=%22a+field+of+cow%22+-shit+-poop+-parsley+-peas+-cabbage+-manure+-pies+-pats+-dung+-corn+-patties&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12970.14888.0.15216.9.9.0.0.0.0.62.426.9.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.CVLfZ6lEYkw) but in almost all references to "a field of cow", *cow* was modifying another noun (e.g. pats, pies, peas).

So I did a Google ngram comparison of ["a field of cows" and "have _NUM_ cow"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+field+of+cows%2Chave+_NUM_+cow&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20field%20of%20cows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20_NUM_%20cow%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20field%20of%20cows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20_NUM_%20cow%3B%2Cc0), and they are comparable:

[image: chart of above link]

Comparing ["have _NUM_ cow" and "have one cow"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+_NUM_+cow%2Chave+one+cow&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20_NUM_%20cow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20one%20cow%3B%2Cc0) shows a difference, and there are 0 hits for "have 1 cow":

[image: chart of above link]

So now I'm wondering what number of cows can be cow? Whereabouts will I hear this usage? Or is the second chart just a clerical error?

Comment: I've never heard of _cow_ as a plural. _Sheep_ and _deer_ are exceptions to the general rule.

Comment: What “have NUM cow” exactly refers to?

Comment: @user067531 \_NUM\_ is a placeholder for numerals

Comment: “Have two/three/four/five/etc. cow” yield no results on NGRAM. My impression is that the NUM is just a false positive.

Comment: _Sheep_ is unusual as a domesticated animal where the singular is used as plural, but there are several others for wild animals, especially those hunted as game: _moose_, _elk_, _grouse_, _ptarmigan_.

Comment: Here, expected research to be shown would surely be results from several respected dictionaries. It's the _jobs_ of their researchers and usage panels to check on this sort of thing. And while most dictionaries will probably give no mention of an invariant plural usage, this should be shown, to stop needless duplication of effort. _Then_ someone could give an answer referencing OED, which would be pretty conclusive.

Comment: That is a way of going about it, but I figured it would be a potentially small dialect or set of dialects, so it probably wouldn't be *in* a dictionary, even the OED.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I have. How does it strike you?

Comment: If the OED hasn't got it, it's very doubtful that it qualifies as on-topic. I see you've 'accepted' an answer that isn't really an answer to your actual question.

Comment: I think some questions are just silly: silly cows [caveat: joke]

Comment: You could use *cow* as a plural in a humorous way. For example, Joe says to Moe, “I hear that Longpurse is planning to set up a herd of buffalo”.  And Moe replies, “Yep, and Shortpurse next door is planning to expand his herd of cow”.  This works because (as we know) *cow* is not a real plural. This means it can be used in *mockery*.

Comment: [ask] or [howtoask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an issue with instances of *cow* used as an attributive noun modifying another plural noun, whether a class that takes a regular plural (e.g., *animals*) or not (e.g., *elk*):

> ... a herd of cow elk ...
>   ... a field of cow animals ...

When I did a search for "herd of cow" I turned up [exactly that kind of result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22herd%20of%20cow%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Google's NGram search has many notable problems, of which this is one. See [my post on EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu) about NGram searches, the point being that there are many kinds of terms that seem to invalidate statistical support from the Corpus. Personally, I use the tool but am very wary about the results. Unless the search terms can be sufficiently sanitized, I can't draw any conclusions.

Comment: In a slightly different way one can speak of a collective of an animal species in the singular. For example, you can say something like the following. "Had you come to the jungle forty years ago you would have found elephant, tiger, rhinoceros, giraffe, etc. But now large animal life has all but disappeared".

Comment: @WS2: True. Part of the difficulty here may be that *cow* is not a class name for a species but the designator of the female of a variety of species. There is no species simply called *cow*, even though we seem to want to use it as a placeholder for *cattle*: **A:** "Lotta cows on the prairie today." **B:** "Some of 'em are bulls and steers."

Comment: I am fortunate, in this respect, of having been brought up in the country, in close contact with farming and animals. But I was recently astonished, when in conversation with an urban intellectual of mature years, that he'd always assumed that, since he knew he wasn't eating "bull", his beef must have come from "cows". I blame the Normans. Their gentry, by insisting on using the French words "beef", "pork", and "mutton" for what was served at the table, have confused the English-speaking world for a millennium.

Comment: @Robusto Plus I imagine some of them are heifers. Probably not oxen though; those ones have a job to do that doesn't involve lazing around the daisy fields all the livelong day.

Comment: @tchrist: That brings up a good point. We have words for some animals that distinguish not only gender (rooster,hen;cow,bull;duck,drake;mare,stallion) but various stages of development (foal,colt/filly), and procreational viability (steer,heifer,cow;mare,stallion). And for others we have no innate distinction at all (male/female wombat, etc.).

Comment: @Robusto — Cow certainly was regarded as the name of a species in its Germanic origin, rather than specifically the female of a species (which distinction arose later). And that species was certainly not *cattle*, which came into the language much later and originally refered to a general collection of animals, rather than specifically bovidae.

Answer (score 5):

**English ‘Irregular’ Plurals**

The poster writes:

> “I noticed that, unlike with sheep or deer, cows is the plural of cow.
>   I started wondering why”

However, this seems to assume that English has some rule for forming plurals of words on the basis of the class of objects described — in this case animals (or even ruminants!), and ignores the facts that the ‘irregular’ plurals of very old words in the English language reflects their individual development from Germanic Old English forms. In most cases such Germanic plurals were replaced, sooner or later, by the plural in ‘s’, the persistence depending to some extent on frequency of usage in the language.

Germanic plurals (which varied with case) were made by different word endings (often *e*, *en* or *n*) or changes in vowel, or both. Examples of words in which these survive include:

> ox — oxen
>   brother — brethren
>   man — men
>   mouse — mice

It can be seen that such plurals that survive in English involve a vowel change or a final ‘n’. Other endings have disappeared entirely, leaving singular and plural identical, these not only include ruminants, but fish such as:

> fish
>  
>   trout
>  
>   cod

**So what precursors or regional variants does ‘cows’ have?**

The first point to make is cow had a plural with both a vowel change and final ‘n’ — [**kine**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kine) —which although now archaic, persisted for a long time before being displaced by the ‘regular’ English  plural, ‘cows’. For example The King James Bible refers to:

> “Thirty milch camels with their colts, forty kine, and ten bulls,
>   twenty she asses, and ten foals”

(Genesis 32:15)

And the OED (Oxford English Dictionary) contains a reference to *Kine-Pox* (Cow-Pox) in a book title from 1800. According to the OED, the plural cows “hardly appears before the 17th c”.

But are their other variant plurals, perhaps regional, as the poster asks? I would regard the OED as a better source in this respect than Google books, as it tends to quote such variants, but the only variant plural mentioned is *ky* or *kye* in the North of England and Scotland.

*So there is no reason to expect a plural ‘cow’ and I do not believe one exists.*

**Footnote: “A chasing the deer”**

The OED lists a variety of examples of Old English plurals: *deor*, *deoran* and *deore*, and in early Middle English (1250 and later) mentions examples of plurals with ‘s’ — *deres*, *dueres*. The form without an ending must have been sufficiently entrenched to resist the tide of change.

Comment: agree. Many words like 'kine' have, of late, been replaced with newer ones.

Comment: Good research, and probably the best answer available. It's moot whether 'Is the word [probably sic] zzxzz ever used?' -type questions should ever be sanctioned, especially where no dictionary research of any kind is attached, and not even any example quotes, but this is admittedly grey-area. A lot of invariant plurals for mammals etc _are_ acceptable, though some have complex distributions. / In this article, 'cow' is used as the generic plural, twice, alongside 'cows': [Thedodo.com: Cow are an enviormental hazard](https://www.thedodo.com/cow-are-an-enviormental-hazard-1145080833.html).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That article has typos. cow will never be plural in English, even a silly one. This is an answer worth upvoting.

Comment: @Lambie Yes I already had done. And downvoted elsewhere (no dictionary research shown). // I wouldn't bet against the invariant plural creeping in and gaining acceptability. 'Police' for instance now has a quasi-count usage. CGEL mentions the term 'quasi-count noun': There are a few plural-only nouns that are not morphologically marked as plural: cattle, livestock, police, poultry ...
'Cattle'  for example cannot be used with low numerals, but is found with high round numerals (and hence might be classified as a ‘quasi-count noun’). Compare: a thousand cattle, ∗ seven cattle

Comment: @EdwinAshworth cattle, a herd of cattle and **head** of cattle. There is no invariant plural for the word cow. My goodness. The article you cite does not use cow as a generic plural. It has two typos.The word "head" is used by farmers when they count the number of cattle that they own. Wikipedia: A farmer might say "My land runs 5,000 head of cattle." A "head" means one, but the term "one head of cattle" is not usually used. It is easier to say "one cow".

Comment: @Lambie And articles containing say 'a thousand cattle'; 'a thousand police'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A thousand head of cattle and a thousand police officers, as we all know.

Comment: @Lambie You're not agreeing with CGEL now. They also allow  'a thousand cattle' and 'a thousand police'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But I am no fundamentalist, just a stylist. Allow indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you were to find 'cow' as a plural it could well be in the farming industry where livestock is often described generically.  I know people in the industry who speak about raising 'chicken' rather than chickens.   But looking through industry magazines online just shows me 'cows', and much more commonly 'cattle'.

Comment: I'm ignoring the advice to add reputable sources. There are hundreds of magazines about livestock.  Any small number I might select proves nothing. Who decides the reputabality of the farming journal.  Any mother tongue English speaker knows the word 'cattle'. I'm calling the advice spurious pedantry for the sake of it.  There should be somewhere on SE to report it.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "till the cow come home" with a plural-sounding verb is the earliest form, in the 3 quotations, 1610-1647, in the early 17th century, when "cows" was not yet the common form per the OED:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/until_the_cows_come_home

Comment: That link makes no suggestion that "… the cow come" is plural, any more than it's a dialect or idiomatic form of "… the cow comes". Given that huge parts of English dialect and idiom find number wholly irrelevant, how does that link count?

Comment: Wrong. _Come_ in that construction in that period is not plural, nor dialect, but singular subjunctive (standard then, but now archaic and nearly extinct). Compare _till he come to fourteen yeares_ (Sir John Doddridge, "The history of the ancient and moderne estate of the principality of Wales,", 1630)

Comment: The subjunctive is ambiguous between singular and plural.  To the modern ear, the idiom is always plural.  Recent quotations (1738-2015) all use the plural form "cows" with various plural verb forms (come, came, had come), so that's 3 centuries of universally plural forms, preceded by a few decades of an ambiguous form.  Since the "cows" form “hardly appears before the 17th c” (per the OED above), transitional usages would be unsettled.  The idiom became fixed as plural, either mistakenly understood as plural, or just updated to contemporary plural forms.  But who keeps just one cow?

Answer (score 0):

The plural of "cow" is cows."

Your search term should be **have _ NUM _ cow,have one cow,have two cow** This will show you that "*NUM*" in the graph is equivalent to the number one only.

Also, you should not use single numbers in Google Ngrams as numbers under ten are usually written in fiull.